# EXTjs: Grid Panel issues - Column Aligment and Loading Data

Tags: extjs, alignment, gridpanel

I saw some post similar to my problem, but the solution are not coinciding with mine. First is that in Grid Panel the columns are not aligned right.

[image]

Secondly, see column 1 has no data? Here is how I made it:

```
// Data Tabe
var storeFields = Schedule.Calendar.panels.CallbackPanel.getDates(true);
storeFields.push('time');
/*
       storeFields will return: [0,0,0,0,.......0,'time']
    */
var callbackdata = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: storeFields,
    data: Ext.create('Schedule.Calendar.data.CallbackData')
});

var callbackTable = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: 'callback-table',
    store: callbackdata,
    columns: [
        { header: 'Time',  dataIndex: 'time', id: 0},
        Schedule.Calendar.panels.CallbackPanel.getDates(false)
                         //This will return
                       /*
                       {
                       header : 0
                       dataIndex: '1'
                       id: 1
                       },
                       {
                       header : 1
                       dataIndex: '2'
                       id: 2
                       }
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       up to 30
                       */
    ],
    stripeRows : true,
    autoScroll: true,
    columnLines: true,
    listeners:{
        itemclick:
        function(grid, record, item, index, event){
            active_id = record.get('id');
        }
    },
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1000,
    height: 435
});
```

I am using Extensible Calendar http://ext.ensible.com , as far as I know I have not included any css files.

heres a snippet of my html:

```
<head>
<title>Extensible : Basic Calendar</title>
<!-- Sets up all Ext and Extensible includes: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Extensible-config.js"></script>

<!-- Page-specific includes -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="basic.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<style>
    .sample-ct {      
        height: 500px;
        width: 1000px
        align: 'center'
    }

    .next-button {
        background-image: url("http://localhost/schedule/resources/images/custom/right_arrow.png");
    }
    .prev-button {
        background-image: url("http://localhost/schedule/resources/images/custom/left_arrow.png");
    }

</style>
```

This my simple data: - it will only accept until 9:30AM. If i comment out 9:30 and below that it works fine, if not the alignment goes crazy.

```
myJsonData: function() {

    var myData = {'items' : [
                    {'time': '1:00 AM'},
        {'time': '1:30 AM'},
        {'time': '2:00 AM'},
        {'time': '2:30 AM'},
        {'time': '3:00 AM'},
        {'time': '3:30 AM'},
        {'time': '4:00 AM'},
        {'time': '4:30 AM'},
        {'time': '5:00 AM'},
        {'time': '5:30 AM'},
        {'time': '6:00 AM'},
        {'time': '6:30 AM'},
        {'time': '7:00 AM'},
        {'time': '7:30 AM'},
        {'time': '8:00 AM'},
        {'time': '8:30 AM'},
        {'time': '9:00 AM'},
        {'time': '9:30 AM'},
        {'time': '10:00 AM'},
        {'time': '10:30 AM'},
        {'time': '11:00 AM'},
        {'time': '12:00 NN'},
        {'time': '12:30 NN'},
        {'time': '1:00 PM'},
        {'time': '1:30 PM'},
        {'time': '2:00 PM'},
        {'time': '2:30 PM'},
        {'time': '3:00 PM'},
        {'time': '3:30 PM'},
        {'time': '4:00 PM'},
        {'time': '4:30 PM'},
        {'time': '5:00 PM'},
        {'time': '5:30 PM'},
        {'time': '6:00 PM'},
        {'time': '6:30 PM'},
        {'time': '7:00 PM'},
        {'time': '7:30 PM'},
        {'time': '8:00 PM'},
        {'time': '8:30 PM'},
        {'time': '9:00 PM'},
        {'time': '9:30 PM'},
        {'time': '10:00 PM'},
        {'time': '10:30 PM'},
        {'time': '11:00 PM'},
        {'time': '12:00 MN'},
        {'time': '12:30 MN'}
    ]};

    return myData;

},
```

Regards,
Ronel C.

Comment: why do u have ids on your columns? your column definitions are missing commas, your styles are missing semicolons ...

Comment: that is just an example that this class, " Schedule.Calendar.panels.CallbackPanel.getDates(false)", will return. Just an example for you to see what those classes returns. As for the Id, i dont know why I put there. I might need it later on i guess. Remove it?

Comment: I got to align right if the data loaded in the store is just a handful. But, when I load 20+ rows, the GridPanel does not align. is this a bug of extjs4? can someone share a fix?

Comment: i load over 100 and its fine, check your data.

Comment: my data is just a simple Json format. See the post again, I updated my post. Thanks

Comment: Hello? any ideas on this? column are still not aligned if data loaded is more than 20 rows. Please help.

Comment: you are not providing all of the information. why is your data in the form of '9:00 AM' but the grid shows 9:00. And what exactly is '12:00 NN' ? Is there a model class that expects certain format? NN and MN are not regular time formats.

Comment: I manually declared the content of the array. This would display as the time column is the only one that has a column. It does display that but the columns are not aligned. Okay let me put on more info.